# RavenDB Deserialization seems slow

Tags: performance, ravendb

I have been playing around with RavenDB (build 531) and I can't seem to get the performance correct.

I have a simple class

```
    public class Cat
    {
      public string Id {get; set;}
      public string Name {get; set;
    }
```

I create about 200 random cats, and put them to RavenDB.

But when I go to fetch **one** cat, via

```
   session.Load<Cat>("cats/<GUID>");
```

it takes about 700 ms.

The Debug window from RavenDB looks like this

```
    Request # 156: GET - **0 ms** - <default>-200-/docs/cats/<GUID>
```

It returns me the correct Cat, but the Deserialization seems to take a long time.

I've tried to deserialize the output from a file, to see if that's really the culprit, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Thoughts?

**Edit:** I tried deserializing just a plain old Cat object, and it took 100 ms.

**Edit2:** Here's the answer.

It appears there is some significant startup costs.

If I fetch any other Cat after my first one, my performance increases significantly -- to < 100 ms.

Hence why you don't benchmark with only one fetch.

Comment: Please post your finding on the subject and accept your answer so it can help other people in the same situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things that could be going on here.

1. Are you using an Index?
2. Have you made -any- calls to the Document Store .. with that query before?

Generally the reason is because

1. First client side call to a Document Server has some initial setup hit.
2. Indexes might need to be indexed - eg. dynamic indexes.

#### More details...

When ever any data is first used in a RavenDB Document Store .. some indexing will be required. This happens when a query is executed and no index is used (or guessed). I think it also happens when an index is first created .. but i'm not 100% certain of that.

So generally, lots of people first just trying querying the Document Store without an index. The initial first hit is always expensive. Creating the initial Document Store (on the client side) is expensive .. [which is why it's suggested to be a Singleton](http://beta.ravendb.net/kb/3/using-ravendb-in-an-asp-net-mvc-website). If the first time that query is executed and it's a dynamic index.. then that index has to be created, indexed and THEN returned to the client.

So there's a fair bit of initial warm-up stuff required for the first hit.

Comment: I was querying using a dynamic index, however the index had already been built. The performance problem was due to the first hit against the Document Store.